# Saving a video to BOOT partition

Tags: boot, sd-card, video, macos

I have a RPi mounted in a very tight space, and occasionally a guy needs to retrieve the SD card and put a video on it for the exhibit.This person is working on OSX and I've overlooked the concept that they can't read Ext partitions.

---

Is it possible for the Mac person to save a video to boot, and for my rc.local program to `mv /boot/video.mp4 /home/pi` if the file exists?

Will saving a video to the boot partition have adverse effects on the Pi's startup?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the Mac person to save a video to boot, and for my rc.local program to mv /boot/video.mp4 /home/pi if the file exists?

Yes, and in fact if you need more room there for this kind of thing you can make the boot partition any size you like (of course, with an existing card this would mean moving the second partition first).

> Will saving a video to the boot partition have adverse effects on the Pi's startup?

As long as it isn't foolishly named `kernel.img` (or something that's already used there) it will be fine.  This should be easy to do using appropriate filename extensions.